# position a cross in the center of a square which scales to the container size

Tags: html, css

I have a container which is a like a model. In the future it will scale based on screen size so im trying to get the div inside it to scale with it.

To make it a perfect square I am giving it a width of x% and then padding-top: x% so it will scale and also be equal on all sides.

This worked until I tried to put a cross inside it using the same method. I have been tweaking it and ive got it so close but now the cross has a small margin on the right I cannot get rid of

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.outer{
   position: absolute;
   top:      0px;
   right:    0px;
   cursor:   pointer;
   background-color: yellow;
   width:  10%;
   padding: 10px;
}

.cross{
  width:  50%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    background:
        linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 43%, black 45%, black 55%, transparent 57%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom left , transparent 43%, black 45%, black 55%, transparent 57%),
        transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='outer'>
    <div class='cross'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what the issue? you need the yellow to remain square?

Comment: yes all the sides should be equal length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add an extra element, add the background coloration to the outer element

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.outer{
   position: absolute;
   top:      0px;
   right:    0px;
   cursor:   pointer;
   background:  /*-2px then + 2px (4px thickness)*/
    linear-gradient(45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 2px),black 0 calc(50% + 2px),#0000 0) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(-45deg,#0000 calc(50% - 2px),black 0 calc(50% + 2px),#0000 0) padding-box,
    yellow;
   width: 10%;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   border: 10px solid #0000; /*to control the margin*/
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='outer'>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Another syntax where you can adjust `background-size`/`background-position`

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.outer{
   position: absolute;
   top:      0px;
   right:    0px;
   cursor:   pointer;
   background:  /*-2px then + 2px (4px thickness)*/
    linear-gradient(45deg, #0000 calc(50% - 2px),black 0 calc(50% + 2px),#0000 0) 50% padding-box no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(-45deg,#0000 calc(50% - 2px),black 0 calc(50% + 2px),#0000 0) 50% padding-box no-repeat,
    yellow;
   background-size: calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px);
   width:  15%;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='outer'>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that is great, I only added the container because i thought the linier always goes to the bottom corners with no padding. Thanks :D

Comment: @RachelDockter we can clip the gradient to content/padding-box ;) so I added a border then I clipped the background to the padding area thus it won't cover the border area that you can use to control the distance

Comment: ahh very smart, I can accept your answer in 2 mins, thanks :)

Comment: @RachelDockter added another syntax where you can rely on background-size/background-position